# Open conering of peojective space

Tags: general-topology

Let $d= dim_R F = $1, 2, or 4, depending on whether F = **R, C** or **H**, respectively. Prove that there is an open covering of $FP^n$ by $\ n+1$ open subsets $U_i$, where $U_i$ is homeomorphic to $F^n$ homeo to $R^dn$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for each $i = 1,2,\ldots,n+1$, consider the open subsets $U_i = \{[a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{n+1}] : a_i \neq 0\}$.